# How to properly listen for UDP packets while doing other things in Visual C#

Tags: c#

Alright, so I'm pretty new to C# and I'm definitely pretty new to graphical programming. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and writing my application in C#.
I have this hunk of code that I've been toying around with for a while. Essentially my program will send the HELLO, to the server, but the server isn't sending HELLO back. I have no firewall in the middle of client and server right now, but the process is getting hung waiting for the reply back. I honestly don't even want to do it this way, I want the listener to always run in the background while the user does other stuff so that my program functions, well normal. So I come to you oh great Stackoverflow... because I am definitely doing it wrong! Could someone please point me the right direction?

*Current Code:*

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[512];
        byte[] result;
        SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
        result = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.password.Text));
        var hash = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "");
        this.send_message("127.0.0.1", 10545, 10545, "HELLO");
        this.send_message("127.0.0.1", 10545, 10545, "AUTH:" + this.login.Text + ":" + hash);

        //ListenForData.Start();

    }

    private void send_message(string server, int localPort, int remotePort, string message)
    {
        label4.Text = "Listening on port:" + localPort;
        IPEndPoint lep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort);
        Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress loginServer = IPAddress.Parse(server.ToString());
        byte[] sendbuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(loginServer, remotePort);
        s.SendTo(sendbuf, ep);

        try
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(lep);
            byte[] bytes = udpClient.Receive(ref lep);
            label4.Text = ep.ToString();
        } catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

**UDPATE:**

```
   private static void UDPListener(object obj)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(10545))
            {
                string rMessage = "";
                string[] rArgs = new string[0];
                while (true)
                {
                    //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                    var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    rMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults.Buffer);
                    rArgs = rMessage.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                    if( rArgs[0] == "HELLO")
                    {
                        Console.Write("Received HELLO from server.");
                        byte[] data = new byte[512];
                        byte[] result;
                        SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
                        result = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj.password.Text));
                        var hash = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "");
                        send_message("127.0.0.1", 10545, 10545, "AUTH:" + obj.login.Text + ":" + hash);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Note a Visual Studio question: that's just the IDE you are using to write .NET code. And the answer: listen for inbound packets asynchronously: [`UdpClient.ReceiveAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159541.aspx).

Comment: Alright @Richard yea that definitely helps, I'm running into other issues now, where my udpListener thread is not able to access the non-static variables from the form though. I need those so that when the client sends hello, and the server sends back a token the client can send back the authentication data along with the token received from the server, completing the authentication process. Right now I have this function loading with the form, but of course I can't get login.Text or password.Text (Form1.login.Text & Form1.password.Text) I also can't pass the object over to the thread.

Comment: Don't use tasks for this, there's no guarantee they'll even run (especially if you have other equally bad code hogging a task thread forever). Use your own thread.

Comment: @Blindy will it be easier to share data between the thread & main application + other threads this way?

Answer (score 3):

You can safely ignore the advice from Blindy. The `UdpClient.ReceiveAsync()` method is specifically designed around the `Task` paradigm, and is much more efficient than dedicating a thread to receiving data. Because the `Task` is awaitable, it's also easier to integrate the `ReceiveAsync()` approach with a GUI program (e.g. Winforms or WPF). That said, for all that to work, you want to execute the `ReceiveAsync()` call in the UI thread, rather than in another `Task`.

Unfortunately, lacking [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your question, it's not possible to say for sure how that would look. But it most likely would involve making your `UDPListener()` method an `async` method and calling it from the UI thread. Also, since you say the method can't access non-static members, the obvious solution to that is to make the method itself non-static. E.g.:

```
private static async Task UDPListener(object obj)
{
    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient(10545))
    {
        string rMessage = "";
        string[] rArgs = new string[0];
        while (true)
        {
            //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
            var receivedResults = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
            rMessage += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults.Buffer);
            rArgs = rMessage.Split(new char[] { ':' });
            if( rArgs[0] == "HELLO")
            {
                Console.Write("Received HELLO from server.");
                byte[] data = new byte[512];
                byte[] result;
                SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
                result = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(obj.password.Text));
                var hash = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "");
                send_message("127.0.0.1", 10545, 10545, "AUTH:" + obj.login.Text + ":" + hash);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is not clear from your updated question whether you have fixed your failed to receive a reply yet. But if you have not changed your `send_message()` method, it has some obvious problems, especially in the context of creating a separate `UdpClient` instance to receive datagrams.

The most obvious issue is that you do not create the `UdpClient` instance which you're expecting to use to receive the response until *after* you have sent the message. This is wrong for two reasons:

1. It's entirely possible that the remote endpoint will send the response before you've created the socket. If that happens, the datagram will just be dropped.
2. More importantly, the usual design for a server is to send a response to the remote endpoint that sent it the message in the first place. I.e. in this case that would be the socket `s`. Even if you did create the `udpClient` object before calling `s.SendTo()`, the reply would actually be sent to the `s` socket, not the `udpClient.Client` socket.

Again, without a good code example it's not possible to know what your server actually does. But whether it behaves like a normal server, or is some non-standard implementation, the code you've posted cannot reliably receive a response from the server.

You should fix your design so that your client creates only a single socket (e.g. an initial `UdpClient` instance). You would prepare for communication by calling `ReceiveAsync()`, and only once you've done that, thus ensuring you're ready to receive a response, then you can *send* data.

Make sure that you create *only* this single object.

Note also that client-side implementations typically do not bind to a specific port. Instead, you let the OS assign a port. Only the server needs to bind to a specific port, so that inbound requests from unknown endpoints can know to what port to send their request. The server's receive operation will include the port number of the client, so the server will know to what port to send its response, without the client having selected any special port number.

Finally, I *strongly* recommend you study existing socket programming tutorials, and especially the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). None of the material there is directly applicable to the .NET socket API, but most of the issues you will have trouble with are *exactly* the kinds of things documented there. It is not possible to use the .NET socket API without also having a good basic comprehension of socket programming generally.

If the above does not get you headed in the right direction, please make sure that any future questions you ask include a good code example, as described in the link I provided above. Note that for any networking question, a complete code example includes *both* the client and server. It is not possible for anyone to fully understand your question, never mind to test and fix your code example, without implementations of both.

Comment: Thanks @Peter that helps alot, I was till getting pretty stuck but I think this will be a great solution to try out. Like I said, I'm kind of new to C# so, like really really new, I'm just kinda learning as I go along picking up a few things here and there. I've always found the best way to learn is to just jump right in and do something... I guess just normal trial & error.